# Ubuntu 12.04 wifi missing in nm

Tags: wireless

I'm a newbie on Ubuntu and i need some help.

I recently got a Ubuntu 12.04 running laptop,

First time I connected to wireless it went flawlessly,

But after i turned it of and started it again wireless networks won't show in network manager and i can't connect to it.

I tried some of the similar problems solutions but nothing helped, such as `sudo apt-get install network-manager`, but it says that nothing is updated `(0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 remove and 0 not upgraded)`.

```
rfkill list 
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

This is what I get when I enter `rfkill list.` Im not sure what o/p is.

And this is the result of `sudo apt-get install nework-manager`:

```
sudo apt-get install nework-manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
network-manager is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  mingw-w64 sbsigntool gir1.2-timezonemap-1.0 realpath efibootmgr diffstat
  libdmraid1.0.0.rc16 libdebconfclient0 binutils-mingw-w64-i686 kpartx-boot
  libopts25 gir1.2-json-1.0 quilt autogen gcc-mingw-w64 user-setup
  gcc-mingw-w64-i686 kpartx rdate binutils-mingw-w64-x86-64
  libdebian-installer4 libopts25-dev btrfs-tools apt-clone localechooser-data
  gcc-mingw-w64-base gcc-mingw-w64-x86-64 archdetect-deb dmraid python-pyicu
  libkms1 mingw-w64-dev gir1.2-xkl-1.0
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: what was the o/p of `rfkill list`?

Comment: rfkill list
1: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
this is whay i get when i enter rfkill list, im not sure what o/p is, and this is the result of sudo apt-get install nework-manager:

Comment: what about wlan in the output of rfkill list?

Comment: i edited the question, how do i check wlan?

Comment: plz post the full output of `rfkill list` in pastebin.com and then post the link here.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ST0cma7a
is this it?

Comment: iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

Answer (score 0):

to check wlan type "iwconfig" in your terminal

also try to add another wi-fi in your network manager

click on "edit connections" then "add" select "wi-fi" select your settings

now you'll have wi-fi in your nm :)

Comment: I tried this already but after i enter the mac, the save button goes shady and i can't press it.
I'm not sure we are on the same page, when i click on nm, and on edit conections it shows wired/wirelles/mobile broadband/vpn/dsl...

Comment: then try connection through the terminal using "ifconfig wlan0 up" 2 "iwlist wlan0 scan" 3 "iwconfig wlan0 essid NETWORKID key WIRELESS_KEY" 4 "dhclient wlan0"

Comment: dell@dell-Inspiron-3537:~$ ifconfig wlan0 up
wlan0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device

dell@dell-Inspiron-3537:~$ iwlist wlan0 scan
wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning.

and the last one:
Error for wireless request "Set ESSID" (8B1A) :
    SET failed on device wlan0 ; Operation not permitted
dell@dell-Inspiron-3537:~$ dhclient wlan0
Cannot find device "wlan0"

Comment: looks like your wifi is not powered on did you switch on the wifi on your laptop??

Comment: I tried turning it on via commands, or i thought i was, cause i read somewhere that it could be turned on manualy. Do you mean is the hardware switch turned on?

Comment: yep the hardware switch as your iwconfig and ifconfig say its not powered on try the drivers and also try rebooting the system once. sry i can't help you much as i need to go out now. merry christmas